# Create a single object from array of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a following data-structure.

```
[
   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: 'A',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
    },

   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: 'B',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   },

   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: 'C',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   }
]
```

I want to group this array into a single object like this. I am basically grouping the `ORG` into a single array.

```
   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: ['A', 'B', 'C']
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried,

Comment: you can get the array of orgs by using filter and map. ex: const orgs = array.filter(arr => arr.NAME=== 'TEST_1').map(arr => arr.ORG); obviously if you need a dynamic name, you have to use variables, and if you need to compare the FROM and TO, you would have to use && FROM ===  && TO ===

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with `reduce` higher order function like so :

```
let arr = [
   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: 'A',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
    },

   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: 'B',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   },

   {
      NAME: 'TEST_1',
      ORG: 'C',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   }
];

let obj = arr.reduce((prev , curr) => { 

  return {
    ...curr,
    ORG : [...(prev['ORG'] || []) , curr['ORG']
  }
} , {});


console.log(obj)
```

And the output is just like this :

```
{ NAME: 'TEST_1',
  ORG: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
  FROM: '20191223',
  TO: '99991231' }
```